# Looking for some information on applications of integer linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, network-flow, binary-programming

I am a grad student in the field of integer linear programming (ILP). If I can find a pattern and make ILPs that are very easy to solve according to that pattern, is it useful and practical? Is there any application for finding some algebraic relation for a special group of ILP, and make this ILP? My question is about 0/1 ILP.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions are easy to find, what you need are problems to fit them...

Depending on how "special" your problems are, they may or may not be useful.

In some cases it may be useful to test an ILP solver on problems that have known optimal solutions (if the solver is not able to take advantage of whatever trick makes these problems easy).